# C - Not properly reading data from a txt file into a linked list

Tags: c, linux, linked-list

So, I am new to C and I am trying to read data from a .txt file into a linked list. I have created an insert function to place each value in the .txt file into the a node in the list. When i try to print out all the data, it just displays the last value in the txt file.

For example:
There are three values in the txt file. 
When i try to print all the values, it will only print the 3rd value, THREE times.

Here is the code:

```
#include "action.h"


void insert(ListPtr *ptr, arPtr *sPtr);
void printList( ListPtr ptr);

int main(void){
int i,num;


// initialize the file pointer
FILE *ptr;//Daily
FILE *PTR;//Group
ListPtr startPtr = NULL;
arPtr dataPtr;

dataPtr = (arPtr) malloc( sizeof( AR));


//dataPtr = {0,0,0,"",""};

//dataPtr = malloc(sizeof ( AR));

int choice = 0;
char groupFile[20];
char dailyFile[20];
dataPtr->location[2] = '\0';
dataPtr->id[6] = '\0';


// Step one: Ask the user what the group file is. 
printf("What is the name of the Daily File you want to load?\nFile Name:\t");
scanf("%s",dailyFile);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//              Read from the group File
if((ptr = fopen(dailyFile,"r+")) == NULL){

    printf("We could not find that Daily File, We will open a new file for you to work with.");

    ptr = fopen(dailyFile,"w");
    choice = 1;
}
else{

    while(!feof(ptr)){

//      fread(dataPtr,sizeof(struct ActionReport),1,ptr);
        printf("Before Scanning");
        fscanf(ptr, "%4d%6s%2s",&(dataPtr->startTime), dataPtr->id, dataPtr->location);
        fgets(dataPtr->description,50,ptr);

    //  if (dataPtr != NULL){

        printf("After Scanning\n\n");

        //check the value that was read from the file
        printf("%4d\t%6s\t%2s\t%10s",dataPtr->startTime,dataPtr->id,dataPtr->location,dataPtr->description);

        insert(&startPtr,&dataPtr);


        //check the value that was placed into the linked list
        printf("%4d\t%6s\t%2s\t%10s",startPtr->ARdata->startTime,startPtr->ARdata->id,startPtr->ARdata->location,startPtr->ARdata->description);

    }//end while
fclose(ptr);
}//elsei

printList(startPtr);
```

Comment: You've not shown the code that actually handles the list (`insert()` and `printList()`) nor the definition of `AR`.

Comment: Do not copy the pointer simply without copying the contents?